# Swift 3 is there a way to print date as Date not as String

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to form a body with date parameter which i have to send to an api. Date gets printed as String format, is there a way to send it as only date format.

```
    let isoDate = "2019-09-21"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!

    let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    let body: [String: Any] = [
        "date": dateStr
    ]
    print(body)
```

It prints :

```
["date": "2019-09-21"]
```

I want it to print it as :

```
["date": 2019-09-21]
```

Comment: Not when printing a `Date`. Why don't you just print `isoDate`?

Comment: @vadian I have to send the date to server as a date not as a string. If i print isoDate directly then it prints as String.

Comment: " server as a date not as a string" Usually, you don't passe a `(NS)Date` object as such. Maybe a UnixTimeStamp or a String representation, but not a Swift Date Object.

Comment: If you send the date to a server it's irrelevant how it gets printed. And how do you send a `Date`(!) instance to a server anyway?

Comment: @Larme i have edited my question with a proper requirement. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the below code :

```
    let isoDate = "2019-09-21"

    let body: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "date": isoDate as AnyObject
    ]
    print(body)
```

This now prints :

```
["date": 2019-09-21]
```

Comment: Almost the entire code is redundant. `let isoDate = "2019-09-21"; let body = ["date": isoDate]"` is sufficient. And never cast a Swift string to `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
```

output:

```
2019-09-21
```

for hour min second you can use :

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date))
```

output:

```
2019-09-21 00:00:00
```

Comment: Hi @Asif, i have edited the question with a proper requirement. Can you please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your example of output looks like DebugDescription of Date.

To convert Date to String you need to call:

```
dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Here is screen from playground:
[image]

Comment: Isn't it a bit pointless to convert the string back to its origin? 

Comment: @vadian I think original code has a string as an input test value

Comment: I just wanted to say that it makes no sense to convert a string to date and then right back to exactly the same string.

Answer (score 0):

```
let isoDate = "2019-09-21"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!
let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
print("\(strDate)")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:isoDate)!
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // 2019-09-21
let body: [String: AnyObject] = [
    "date": dateFormatter.string(from: date) as AnyObject
]
print(body) //["date": 2019-09-21]

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // 2019-09-21 00:00:00
```

Comment: Hi @Bhadresh Kathiriya, i have edited the question with a proper requirement. Can you please help me with this.